# Ionic: Zoom whole app (let the app appear bigger)

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I usually optimize my apps for screen sizes like the iPhone 5.
When everything is done, and I simulate the app on screens like iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+, the app looks really silly, as the fonts, and buttons, etc. are too small and everything looks not polished.

So I made the following statement:

```
/* iPhone 6 */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
  html {
    zoom: 112% !important;
  }
}

/* iPhone 6+ */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
  html {
    zoom: 125% !important;
  }
}
```

This works great in the browser, where I simulate an iPhone 6+. Everything looks like the app on an iPhone 5.
But if I transfer the app to a real device, or the Xcode simulator, the `zoom` directive does not work anymore (everything seems like there is no `zoom` declared).

Do you know how I can achieve my goal?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you set your  [`<meta name="viewport">`](https://css-tricks.com/probably-use-initial-scale1/) and [`@viewport`](http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/) to `initial-scale=1`? Here's docs on [`iStuff`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)@Safari. This is how you typically control display on mobile.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same issue. Actually, the UI is zoomed, but not the text...